# In Go, how do you isolate packages that return more than a primitive value?

Tags: go, interface, architecture, covariance

If I have a `requests` package that defines an interface `TextExtractor` with a `GetText` method that returns a `Text` type, the implementations must fulfill the `TextExtractor` contract *exactly*, and they are forced to import the `Text` type.

I have two possible implementations of `TextExtractor` - one that uses AWS Comprehend and one that uses AWS Textract.

#### File *aws_comprehend.go*

```
package aws_comprehend

type AwsComprehend struct{}

func (a *AwsComprehend) GetText() *Text {
    // do some stuff with aws comprehend...
    return &Text{
        Text:     "text",
        Language: "language",
    }
}

type Text struct {
    Text string
    Language string
}
```

#### File *request.go*

```
package requests

import "fmt"

type TextExtractor interface {
    GetText() *Text
}

type Text struct {
    Text     string
    Language string
}

func HandleRequest(textExtractor TextExtractor) {
    text := textExtractor.GetText()
    fmt.Println(text)
}
```

#### File *main.go*

```
package main

import (
    "aws_comprehend"
    "requests"
)

func main() {
    textExtractor := new(aws_comprehend.AwsComprehend)

    requests.HandleRequest(textExtractor)
    // this does not work:
    // cannot use textExtractor (variable of type *aws_comprehend.AwsComprehend) as
    //         requests.TextExtractor value in argument to requests.HandleRequest:
    //         *aws_comprehend.AwsComprehend does not implement requests.TextExtractor
    //         (wrong type for method GetText)
    //     have GetText() *aws_comprehend.Text
    //     want GetText() *requests.Text
}
```

I understand why this doesn't work. It's because Go doesn't support [Covariant Result Types](https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types). But my question is, what is the standard way to code this situation? The fact that Go provides implicit interfaces means that isolating packages is very easy: the calling package defines the interfaces that it uses, and it is passed implementations that fulfill those interfaces. This means that **packages don't have to reference each other at all**. But if a package defines an interface that returns anything more than a primitive value, then you have to deliberately share those value types. The code above would be fine if `GetText` returned a `string`. But the fact that it returns a `struct` or another interface, means the code can't be written this way.

I want the `requests` package not to know anything about the `aws_comprehend` package. This is because I have two implementations of the `TextExtractor` interface: One that uses AWS Comprehend, and one that uses AWS Textract. I *also* would prefer not to include a "intermediate" package that has interfaces that both the `requests` package and the `aws_comprehend` package inherit from. If both packages have to inherit the same interface, then it seems like it's just indirect coupling to me and it ruins the idea of implicit interfaces.

I understand that Go is very opinionated. So what is the standard way to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

First, your file layout is not valid. You can’t have two files in the same folder, with different packages. So below is a corrected layout. Also I removed all pointers, because they aren't needed for this example and are just distracting.

Finally, I updated the method to return the correct type, so that the code actually compiles:

`aws_comprehend/aws_comprehend.go`:

```
package aws_comprehend

import "hello/requests"

type AwsComprehend struct{}

func (AwsComprehend) GetText() requests.Text {
   return requests.Text{}
}
```

`requests/request.go`:

```
package requests

import "fmt"

type TextExtractor interface {
   GetText() Text
}

type Text struct {
   Language string
   Text     string
}

func HandleRequest(textExtractor TextExtractor) {
   text := textExtractor.GetText()
   fmt.Println(text)
}
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
   "hello/aws_comprehend"
   "hello/requests"
)

func main() {
   var textExtractor aws_comprehend.AwsComprehend
   requests.HandleRequest(textExtractor)
}
```

Comment: I think the OP's question was how do you do this *without* having the `Text` type imported into both libraries.